# Is using lgbt supported services haram?

Tags: halal-haram, practical-islam, sharia

Salam
What if you wanted for example to buy a car from Mercedes Benz, a company that supports lgbt? Would it be haram to buy the car since they support lgbt? Same with for example using Disney+ or playing on Xbox, companies that support lgbt. Would it be haram to use these services?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't consider it to be haram.

You are not responsible for whatever someone does with the money you give them.
For example, You lend your friend $10. Now, what your friend does with that money is up to him and Allah. If he spends it on good, then it's good. If he spends it on bad, then it's on him, not you because you're not responsible for that money anymore.
Likewise, if you pay for something from a company that is "pro-LGBT" but its sole purpose is not to advocate that haram practice, it shouldn't be considered haram.

Obviously, if the company was pro-LGBT and donates a lot of its earnings to LGBT groups to spread their haram fitnah, then yes it would because by giving them money, you're helping them to achieve their success by spreading this fitnah.

If that was the case, imagine how many companies, brands, etc. you wouldn't be able to buy from.

Answer (score -1):

Islam has no restrictions on buying from and selling to Non-Muslims. We sell to and buy from Hindu who according to our faith commit shirk which is much more than supporting LGBT.